# Apply Laravel 4 query cache to all database reads

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Laravel 4 has a **query cache** built into its **query builder**: just `add ->remember()`, according to the docs.

Can anybody tell me how I can apply this method to **all** queries in my application, **without** appending `->remember()` to each and every database call in it? Some kind of after filter, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to extend the query builder and simply overload the `get()` method to first call `remember()`, and then do the `get()` statement.

Practically, though, if you want to cache every single query, you might as well just do this at the database level. MySQL, for example, has a configuration option to automatically cache all queries for a certain amount of time. However, in an application that does a lot of inserts/updates/deletes, this will have poor performance since the cache is cleared for that table on every such call.

Using Laravel for every query would also mean getting outdated data if you do inserts/updates/deletes meanwhile, so you'd have to clear the cache every time you update.

Best practice would be to diligently decide if a query should be cached or not.